# Determine file-script directory at runtime from clojure

Tags: clojure, namespaces

I am creating a third-party library for Clojure. In the core of this library I need to run script from the operation system. In this case I cannot use absolute path to this file like this `/Users/me/src/clojure-pymorphy/src/pymorphy/pymorphy.py`.

But if I use relative path `script/script.py` - than sometimes location of the script could be determined as wrong. It depends on the directory from which I run/use this clojure library. Because this library will be distributed as the third-party I need the way to determine the path of `script.py` from Clojure source code.

Project folders looks like this:

```
clojure-pymorphy/
    src/
        pymorphy/
            pymorphy.py
        pymorphy.clj
```

Script `pymorphy.py` is invoked from `pymorphy.clj`. File `pymorphy.clj` begins from this lines:

```
(ns pymorphy
  (:import  (java.util ArrayList)
            (jep Jep)))
```

I've tried to find out is there a way to determine directory to `pymorphy` namespace at runtime and just simply add `"pymorphy/pymorphy.py"` to it. But after many hours of googling I come to conclusion that it's not possible.

So is there any other ways to dynamically determine path to clojure namespace at runtime?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you to run this script, so this will be something like - this will copy script to temp file, and run it. You need to create file, because if you'll pack everything into jar, then interpreter won't be able to read file..

```
(let [tmp (File/createTempFile "tmp" "py")
      script (clojure.java.io/resource "pymorphy/pymorphy.py")]
  (try
    (when (and script (.exists tmp))
      (with-open [os (.openStream script)]
        (clojure.java.io/copy os tmp))
      (run-script....))
    (finally
      (when (.exists tmp)
        (.delete tmp)))))
```

Comment: It works in any ways but my method didn't work if library is used as third-party. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

While looking at the similar questions at stackoverflow I find the solution:

```
(.getFile (clojure.java.io/resource "pymorphy/pymorphy.py"))
```

Comment: Be aware that this relies on the directory containing pymorphy being on the classpath of the JVM (strictly of the classloader that loaded the class making the call). Looks like that's fine for your specific use case, but this won't work in the general case. The ClassLoader abstraction does not insist on files being the underlying store, so you can never guarantee to get the absolute path to a file, because there may be no such file. For instance some of clojure's generated classes are not stored in this way